# Nhibernate Self-reference Mapping

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Olá,
Preciso de retornar uma lista de objetos filhos do mesmo tipo do pai. porém, utilizando o nhibernate, o mesmo só retorna um objeto filho, enquanto no banco tenho 3 filhos. Segue abaixo trechos do código:

**Etapa Dados**

```
    public Etapa ObterPorId(int id, bool completo = false)
    {
        if (!completo) return base.ObterPorId(id);
        using (var session = HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Query<Etapa>()
                //.Fetch(e => e.EtapaFilhas) // já tentei com este tb..
                .FetchMany(e => e.EtapaFilhas).FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

**EtapaMap:**

```
public class EtapaMap:ClassMap<Etapa>
{
    public EtapaMap()
    {   
        Table("TEMA_ETAPA");
        Not.LazyLoad();

        Id(i => i.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.Identity();

        HasMany(e => e.EtapaFilhas)
        .Cascade.DeleteOrphan().KeyColumn("id_TEMA_ETAPA_pai");

        References(e => e.EtapaPai).Column("id_TEMA_ETAPA_pai");
        References(e => e.Tema).Column("id_TEMA_FORMULARIO");
    }
}
```

**Etapa (entidade)**

```
public class Etapa
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Etapa EtapaPai { get; set; }
    public virtual Tema Tema { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<Etapa> EtapaFilhas { get; set; }

}
```

**Método de teste:**

```
        [Test]
        public void DeveRetornarQuantidadeDeFilhas()
        {
            var etapaPaiId = 13;

            var sut = new EtapaDados();

            var result = sut.ObterPorId(etapaPaiId, true).EtapaFilhas;

            Assert.That(result.Count, Is.EqualTo(3));
        }
```

Usando LinqPad ou EF, o mesmo retorna 3 filhos. Creio que posso está errando no mapeamento ou no método de chamada de dados, mas não sei como corrigir.

Como alternativa, criei um método que retorna apenas os filhos. Entretanto eu queria evitar esta abordagem, uma vez que deveria acessar os seus filhos através da propriedadade `ISet<Etapa> EtapaFilhas`:

```
    public IEnumerable<Etapa> ObterFilhas(int idEtapaPai)
    {
        using (var session = 
        HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
            return session.Query<Etapa>()
                .Where(e => e.EtapaPai.Id == idEtapaPai)
                .ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o resolver este problema, encontrei duas abordagens válidas:

`Where().FetchMany().Single()`

ou

`Where().FetchMany().AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()`

O problema é que o `First()` e suas variações propaga um `select top 1` limitando o resultado da query.

**Solução na prática:**

```
    public Etapa ObterPorId(int id, bool completo = false)
    {
        if (!completo) return base.ObterPorId(id);
        using (var session = HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            var approachOne = session.Query<Etapa>()
                .Where(e => e.Id == id)
                .Fetch(e => e.EtapaFilhas)
                .Single();

            var approachTwo = session.Query<Etapa>()
                .Fetch(e => e.EtapaFilhas).AsEnumerable()
                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

            return approachOne;
        }
    }
```

**AsEnumerable()**

Conforme escreveram Dr Gabriel . Schenker e Aaron Cure, no seu livro NHibernate 3 Beginner's Guide, a instrução "`AsEnumerable`" é usada para alternar o contexto de [LINQ para "NHibernate" para LINQ para objetos] sem disparar a execução da consulta.

Agora, sempre que iterar sobre o resultado da consulta, o **provedor LINQ** sabe qual parte da árvore de expressão para tomar e converter em uma instrução SQL, que pode ser executada a partir do banco de dados.

Sugiro também como referência **stack** [NHibernate: Why does Linq First() force only one item in all child and grandchild collections with FetchMany()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380494/nhibernate-why-does-linq-first-force-only-one-item-in-all-child-and-grandchil).